# Save stage as image including background image

Tags: html, background, kineticjs, todataurl

I'm developing a drag-drop aplication where the user has to be able to drag apples over a tree and save this composition as image. If I only put the code of the draggable apples everything works fine, but when I add the layer containing the background image, the button "Save as image" doesn't open the new tab with the image. Can someone help me please? Here's the code:

```js
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script defer>
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 400,
    height: 475
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

//START BACKGROUND TREE

var background = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        var bgImage = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: imageObj,
          width: 400,
          height: 475
        });

        // add the shape to the layer
        background.add(bgImage);

        // add the layer to the stage
        stage.add(background);
  layer.moveToBottom();
  layer.setZIndex(1);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4nfgxyhzelubl1z/tree.jpg';


//END BACKGROUND TREE

// put the paths to your images in imageURLs
var imageURLs = [];
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9bgkgx41qkel8oo/apple.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9bgkgx41qkel8oo/apple.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9bgkgx41qkel8oo/apple.png");
var imagesOK = 0;
var imgs = [];

// fully load every image, then call the start function
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function () {
            imagesOK++;
            if (imagesOK >= imageURLs.length) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror = function () {
            alert("image load failed");
        }
        img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }
}

function start() {
    // the imgs[] array holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

    // make each image into a draggable Kinetic.Image
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: i * 75 + 15,
            y: i * 20 + 200,
            width: 50,
            height: 53,
            image: imgs[i],
            draggable: true
        });
        layer.add(img);
    }
    layer.draw();
 layer.moveToTop();
 layer.setZIndex(100);
}


      document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
        /*
         * since the stage toDataURL() method is asynchronous, we need
         * to provide a callback
         */
        stage.toDataURL({
  width: 800,
        height: 566,
        mimeType: "image/png",
          callback: function(dataUrl) {
            /*
             * here you can do anything you like with the data url.
             * In this tutorial we'll just open the url with the browser
             * so that you can see the result as an image
             */
            window.open(dataUrl);
          }
        });
      }, false);
    </script>
```

```css
#buttons {
        left: 10px;
        top: 0px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
      }

button {
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: block;
      }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<div id="buttons">
      
  <button id="save">
  Save as image
  </button>
      
</div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ruben_on/cqezv9t0/

Thanks!

Comment: Kineticjs is throwing an error as you can see in the console: *"Kinetic warning: Unable to get data URL. The operation is insecure"*. I think it's because the images you're using are from another domain/website. Try using images which are hosted on your domain.